# BeautifulSoup to access available bikes in DC bikeshare

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to programming and python and am trying to access the  number of available bikes at a given station in the DC bikeshare program.  I believe that the best way to do that is with BeautifulSoup.  The good news is that the data is available in what appears to be a clean format here: https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml

Here's an example of a station:

```
<station>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>15th & S Eads St</name>
    <terminalName>31000</terminalName>
    <lastCommWithServer>1460217337648</lastCommWithServer>
    <lat>38.858662</lat>
    <long>-77.053199</long>
    <installed>true</installed>
    <locked>false</locked>
    <installDate>0</installDate>
    <removalDate/>
    <temporary>false</temporary>
    <public>true</public>
    <nbBikes>7</nbBikes>
    <nbEmptyDocks>8</nbEmptyDocks>
    <latestUpdateTime>1460192501598</latestUpdateTime>
</station>
```

I'm looking for the `<nbBikes>` value.  I had what I thought would be the start of a python script that would show me the value for the first 5 stations (I'll tackle picking the station I want once I get this under control) but it doesn't return any values.  Here's the script:

```
# bikeShareParse.py - parses the capital bikeshare info page 


import bs4, requests

url = "https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml"

res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

#create the soup element from the file
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("res.text", "lxml")

# defines the part of the page we are looking for
nbikes = soup.select('#text')

#limits number of results for testing
numOpen = 5
for i in range(numOpen):
        print nbikes
```

I believe that my problem (besides not understanding how to format code correctly in a stack overflow question) is that the value for `nbikes = soup.select('#text')` is incorrect.  However, I can't seem to substitute anything for '#text' to get any values, let alone the ones I want.

Am I approaching this the right way?  If so, what am I missing?

thanks

Comment: if you are getting the data in xml format you try it using xmletree.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like a big part of my problem may have been trying to use BeautifulSoup for xml.  I tried to create a new script that is basically this: `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree('https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print root`

Comment: This returns the URL.  Trying to get deeper in to the structure with lines like `root1 = ET.fromstring('station') print root1` gets me syntax errors

Comment: this has some good info too: http://www.plotsofdots.com/archives/68

Answer (score 0):

This script creates a dictionary with the structure [station_ID, bikes_remaining].  It is modified from the beginning of this: http://www.plotsofdots.com/archives/68

```
# from http://www.plotsofdots.com/archives/68


import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib2

#we parse the data using urlib2 and xml
site='https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml'
htm=urllib2.urlopen(site)
doc = ET.parse(htm)

#we get the root tag
root=doc.getroot()
root.tag

#we define empty lists for the empty bikes
sID=[]
embikes=[]
#we now use a for loop to extract the information we are interested in
for country in root.findall('station'):
    sID.append(country.find('id').text)
    embikes.append(int(country.find('nbBikes').text))

#this just tests that the process above works, can be commented out
#print embikes
#print sID

#use zip to create touples and then parse them into a dataframe
prov=zip(sID,embikes)

print prov[0]
```

Comment: Shouldn't be an answer unless it sorts the problem